# java8 ZonedDateTime doesnt print EST current time. What am I doing wrong here

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, localdate, zoneddatetime

below is the code I have to print out the current EST date time, but it prints out time in my Time zone which is Arizona Time. What am I missing in this code. Thankyou!

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime .now();

    ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.of ( datetime , ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" ) );
    System.out.println(zdtNewYork.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

You captured Arizona date and time-of-day, then slapped on a time zone to claim (incorrectly) that New York has the same time-of-day at that moment.

So of course when you generated text to display these values, you saw the time-of-day first captured in Arizona. At no point did you *adjust* from Arizona to New York.

## `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class

Never use `LocalDateTime` for tracking moments. By definition, that class cannot represent a specific moment in time, a point on the timeline. It holds a date and time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Telling us "Noon on the 23rd of January this year" is meaningless if we do not know whether you meant noon in Tokyo Japan, Kolkata India, Paris France, or Montréal Québec — all very different moments, hours apart.

## Always specify time zone

To compound on using the wrong class, you called `LocalDateTime.now` without specifying the time zone. So your JVM’s current default time zone was implicitly applied. You claim that default is some time zone in Arizona. So that would be zone applied.

So, you captured the date & time-of-day as seen in Arizona. But then you discarded the fact that the value was in Arizona time zone, because of your use of `LocalDateTime`. Discarding the time zone is the entire point of the `LocalDateTime` class. There are cases where that is useful, but certainly not in your situation.

You then took that Arizona date & time-of-day, and claimed that was the date and time in New York. The actual time-of-day in New York was hours ahead of that, so you told a fib. Lastly you generated text showing that fib.

In other words, apparently you thought this line:

```
ZonedDateTime.of ( datetime , ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" ) )
```

…adjusted from Arizona to New York. But that `datetime` argument no longer knows it came from Arizona, because **`LocalDateTime` has no concept of zone/offset**. No adjustment was made.

You can think of it this way:

> `LocalDateTime` = date + time-of-day
>
> `OffsetDateTime` = date + time-of-day + offset
>
> `ZonedDateTime` = date + time-of-day + zone
>
> `Instant` = date + time-of-day + UTC

Instead, I recommend *always* specifying explicitly your desired/expected time zone. Even if you want the current default time zone, say so explicitly by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault` so any programmer reading your code knows your intention clearly. Letting the time zone or offset-from-UTC be optional is one of the few things I would change in the otherwise amazing class design found in *java.time*. Making the zone/offset arguments required would help to educate more programmers about date-time handling.

## `ZonedDateTime` is the right class

To represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/f8cduV).

> zdt.toString(): 2019-03-04T18:17:08.014-05:00[America/New_York]

## Generate text

We can generate the text you want easily.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/f8cduV).

> 03/04/2019 18:17:08.014

## Adjusting zones

If you do want to adjust between zones, call the [`ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)) method.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtPhoenix = ZoneDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Phoenix" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdtPhoenix.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

Notice the phrase `SameInstant` that means you want the same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline, but you want to see it through the wall-clock time used by the people of the New York region.

## Time zones

> print out the current EST date time

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use or refer to the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime .now(ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" ));

       System.out.println(datetime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")));
```

Comment: Using wrong class. `LocalDateTime` class discards crucial info about time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this class cannot be used to track moments.

Comment: The thing is she didn't want to have zone info at all, but to have a current date and time from a specific zone( in her case America/NewYork ) , which is achieved with this line LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime .now(ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" )); @BasilBourque

Comment: Read [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993245/642706) for a full explanation. You are conflating the output with the input. The formatting of the string output is really beside the point. The OP captured an Arizona date-time, slapped on a New York zone, and then wondered why the string generated displayed an Arizona time. Generating a string, and the `DateTimeFormatter`, is not the problem. Tip: Never choose the `LocalDateTime` simply to control the generating of text. Use the data type appropriate to the *meaning of the data* not the format of the textual output.

Comment: Output must follow input, there is nothing wrong in the output regarding retrieving information about a DATE and TIME of New York needed as per Julia request. Code made here obtains current date-time from the system clock in the specified time-zone, America/New York and works something like " using zone, America/New York convert Instant to DateTime ".

Comment: Same number of steps would have been made for ZoneDateTime example( ZoneDateTime UTC -> ZoneDateTime America/New York ). Anyhow, both answers are good, if you, for some reason would like to have LocalDateTime as New York time, go this way, if you want to have ZoneDateTime of New York time( if you need info about zone ) go another way( I prefer this way too, but I need to object that nothing is wrong with LocalDateTime in this case as well for reason mentioned above ). @BasilBourque

Comment: The code is not incorrect for the question asked, it’s just not recommended to throw the time zone information away in the same moment you’ve got the time as `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId)` does.